# Passing variable from one action class to another in cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Hi I need to put a key in one action class of cucumber and retrieve the same in different action class of cucumber.

Eg:
I have the variable stored in say a=100 in one action class and retrieve it in other action class.What  should I do?

Comment: Setting the variable as static doesn't help ?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the dependency injection you will able to achieve the same. So I recommend you to start with the Cucumber picocontainer. Do not make anything static if you are planning to do the parallel execution. If you really need to get more details about cucumber picocontainer then you visit the below link

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/sharing-test-context-between-cucumber-step-definitions/